# Not sure where this infinite loop is coming from

Tags: c++

I'm coming from C into C++, I might be missing something very basic.

I'm trying to make a program with the collatz conjecture.
Before the first iteration of the loop, i and j both correctly equal 1 and 10.
However, the value of i never seems to change although I have i++ in my loop.

I thought this would be a quick program to code but I'm getting hung up on this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int n, j, i, count = 0;

cin >> n >> j;

for (i = n; i < j; i++){
    while (i != 1){
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            i = i/2;
        else
            i = 3*i + 1;
    }
    count++;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: The way to debug such basic issues is to use a debugger or even basic debug print statements. Surely you can do more for yourself before asking for help.

Comment: The `while` loop sets `i` back to `1`.

Comment: and is j's purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that after you've run the `while` loop that tests whether the conjecture is true for `i`, `i` is by definition set back to `1` (since that's the condition to get out of the loop), so `i++` keeps incrementing from `1` to `2` each time. You'll never get past `2`.

If you're trying to test the Collatz Conjecture for all the numbers from `n` to `j`, you need to use a different variable in the `while` loop than you use for iteration.

And if `count` is supposed to tell you how many cycles are needed, you need to zero it before each `while` loop, and increment it inside the `while` loop.

```
int n, j, i;

cin >> n >> j;

for (i = n; i < j; i++){
    int test = i;
    int count = 0;
    while (test != 1){
        if (test % 2 == 0) {
            test = test/2;
        } else {
            test = 3*test + 1;
        }
        count++;
    }
    cout << i << ' ' << count << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what it's all about, but here's some quick observation:

your `while(i != 1)` loop means that it will either run indefinetely, or when this loop ends `i` will be equal to `1`. Which means that your `for (i = n; i < j; i++){` loops will always restart with `i=1`. No wonder it's a dead loop.

Comment: The Collatz Conjecture states that the loop will always end. It hasn't been proven, but most mathematicians think it's true.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure about details, but from the while loop it's obvious that when it ends `i` will be `1`. So, the `for` loop starting from second iteration will always restart with `i=1` and will keep repeating the same stuff for each consecutive iteration

Comment: I know that, I said so in my first comment on the question, and in my own answer. I was just addressing the possibility of whether it will run indefinitely.

Comment: @Barmar The code was actually fixed. Now it's not the same. It was `while(i!=1)` now `i` isn't changed in the loop: `while (test != 1){`

Answer (score 0):

> Before the first iteration of the loop, i and j both correctly equal 1 and 10.

The let's replay the second iteration of the outer loop.

Before it, at the end of the first iteration, `i` has been incremented to equal 2. Now,

1. `i % 2 == 0` => `i := i / 2`, i.e. `i := 1`.
2. Now `i == 1`, inner loop ends.
3. `i` is incremented and now equals 2.
4. Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the loop variable to a new variable in every loop iteration `i = k` in this case, so that the for loop variable is not affected

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int min, max, count = 0;
    std::cin >> min >> max;

for (int k = min; k <= max; ++k){ 
      i = k;
      while (i != 1)
      {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                    i /= 2;
            else
                    i = 3*i + 1;
            count++;
            std::cout << i << std::endl; //ONLY IF U WANT TO PRINT i EVERY ITERATION                                                                                                                    
      }
      std::cout << "Number of iterations needed: " << count << " for i = " << i << std:: endl;
}
```

Comment: The outer loop appears to be for testing whether the conjecture is true for a range of inputs.